# FusedLocationApi sometimes not working with GPS

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I have an application implemented with *Google's new "FusedLocationAPI"*. It works fine with most devices, except for my **Huawei Ascend G525** with `Android` version `4.1.2`.

If I turn on the "location" first then *install the app* ıt is ok. However, if I *turn off* `location` then *install the application*, go into the `app`, then go back to `Settings` screen to `Force Stop` or do whatever to close it, turn on `location` and go in again, the `GPS` icon on top bar appears but it never calls to `onLocationChanged`.

It only works if I *restart* the device or *turn off* the `GPS` (it is automatically turned on when I turn on `location`), so I think the problem is with `GPS`.

Yet `FusedLocationAPI` does not provide an option to use `Network_Provider` only, so **how am I supposed to overcome this issue**?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I have it too.